# Facebook Insights API unique clicks

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to match columns of Ad statistics from Ads Manager with the one I get through insight API (Marketing API), namely, Unique Link Clicks. Which field from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup/insights/v12.0#fields does it correpond to?

Answer (score 0):

I may not have fully understood the question you asked, but you say that you will make a painting, I think the ones in the image can work.[cost per unique clicks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3WdO.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).